# Generate two words sentence from full sentence (combinations)

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a solution, where I can generate two words sentences from a full sentence.

Example:
Word: "iPad Mini 32GB White"
I would like that to be splitted up to two words sentences
Example:

"iPad Mini", "iPad 32GB", "iPad White" etc.

The combinations should only be used once, so it doesn't generate the same word, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: What are the criteria for something being a sentence? Do you just want to select two random words from each string? Is this a question about programming or about the semantics of language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick pseudo code:

```
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
for ($i=0; $i < count($words); $i++)
    for ($j=($i+1); $j < count($words); $j++)
        echo $words[$i] . ' ' . $words[$j];
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!